# Mongodb query that says "only this field" instead of having to reject each field one-by-one?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there a way to say "I only want this key" when you limit your query using a  in Mongodb? Or do you have to always actively reject fields using {key_one:0}

For example. I only want to pull the value of key_four with my db.tonight.find().

**json structure**

```
{

  key_one : "some string",
  key_two: "some string",
  key_three : "some string",
  key_four: "some string",
  key_five: "some string",
  key_six: "some string"

}
```

How to simplify this?

**Query:**

```
db.tonight.find({},{_id:0,key_six:0,key_five:0,key_three:0,key_two:0,key_one:0})
```

Comment: you can do `{_id:0, key_one:1}` that should have the same effect

Comment: Let me check this. I think I screwed up the syntax. Need to edit question to get test working.

Comment: I'll come back this tonight. I have to go. The example I gave is faulty.

Comment: @Sammaye Made the test data simple to get to the point. You are right. I was confused because you can reject _id, want one of the keys, but you can mix-match rejecting, accepting with the other keys. `key_one:1` basically means I only want this value.

Comment: If you specifically state only keys to include then it will only include those keys and omit all others, or should anyway, i.e. `{field:1}` will omit all other keys as well

Comment: except for _id.  That will always be included unless you explicitly exclude it.

Comment: @Sammaye I figured that out after your comment. By the way, if you want to answer the question, I'll give you the credit.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky That confused me at first with the id. It led me to think you had to include, exclude fields one-by-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way: `db.tonight.find({},{_id:0, key_four:1})`

Comment: Yeh, that's right now. But same as what Sammaye said so I think I need to give that too Sammeye if he wants to answer officially. ;D

Comment: You get the reps for being pro-active in answering! ;D